# If $\frac {\sin^4\theta}a +\frac {\cos^4\theta}b=\frac 1 {a+b}$ P.T $\frac {\sin^8\theta}{a^3} + \frac {\cos^8\theta} {b^3} = \frac1{(a+b)^3}$

Tags: trigonometry

The question reads if
$$\frac {\sin^4\theta}  {a} + \frac {\cos^4\theta}  {b} = \frac 1 {a+b}$$ 
 Then prove that 
$$\frac {\sin^8\theta}  {a^3} + \frac {\cos^8\theta}  {b^3} = \frac 1 {(a+b)^3}$$

I know simply cubing the first equation would not work. I have also tried arriving at the solution using various identities like $ \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ but to no avail. I would also like to know the approach one should use while solving such trigonometry questions.

I am an eleventh grader so sorry if this question is too silly.

Comment: It's a bit long, but solve for $sin \theta$ or $\sin^2 \theta$ from first equation, actually this equation is even valid upto nth power of $(a+b)$ with a little variation of powers of sines and cosines.

Comment: @Mann The full solution for this specific question isn't necessary. What I'm more concerned with is the approach I should have on such kind of questions.

Comment: Actually I just checked my older book, there's a error in your question it should be. $sin^{4}\theta$ and $\cos^{4} \theta$ in first equation.

Comment: @Mann Yeah. Sorry about that :P But as I said, I'm not very concerned with the full solution to this specific problem, the approach is what matters to me the most.

Comment: Well, best way is still to solve for $\sin ^{2} \theta$ lol. Believe me, you'd get a good enough chain.

Comment: @Mann And what about other proving trigonometry questions in general? Anything other than practice, practice and practice? :p

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23760/we-love-math-physics-chemistry-and-random-talk , come in here. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sin^2 \theta = k$

Then our equation is.

$$\frac{k^2}{a}+\frac{(1-k^2)^2}{b}=\frac{1}{a+b}$$

I won't solve the whole equation but i will put in some steps. 
We will be getting something messy like:
$$k^2ab+k^2b^2+a^2+a^2k^2-2a^2k^2+ab+abk^2-2abk=ab$$

And the best part is this all simplifies to:

$$(k\times (a+b)-a)^2=0$$

Hence $k=\frac{a}{a+b}=\sin^2 \theta$

$(1-k)=\frac{b}{a+b}=\cos^2 \theta$

Let us prove the general case. $$\frac{\sin^{4n}\theta}{a^{2n-1}}+\frac{\cos^{4n} \theta}{b^{2n-1}}=\frac{1}{(a+b)^{2n-1}}$$

Substituting our values on LHS.

$$\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}}\times \left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^{2n}+\frac{1}{b^{2n-1}}\times \left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^{2n}$$

$$\frac{a}{(a+b)^{2n}}+\frac{b}{(a+b)^{2n}}=\frac{1}{(a+b)^{2n-1}}=RHS$$ Hence result is true $\forall$ $n \in N$

Comment: Would induction help in the general case?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{\sin^4\theta}{a}=x$ and $\frac{\cos^4\theta}{b}=y$ 
Cubing $(x+y)$
$(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$ 
Substituting.. 
$\frac1{(a+b)^3}=\frac{\sin^{12}\theta}{a^3}+\frac{\cos^{12}\theta}{b^3}+3\frac{\sin^4\theta\cos^4\theta}{ab}(\frac{\sin^4\theta}{a}+\frac{\cos^4\theta}{b})$ 

Now equate this expression to $\frac {\sin^8\theta}{a^3} + \frac {\cos^8\theta} {b^3}$ And LHS=RHS. Hence proved.

Comment: Thanks :) Could you specify what approach you generally use for such questions?

Comment: You just changed your question, let me change it. For your comment, I just use hairy algebra nothing else.! BTW I am one year younger than you.

Comment: Are you sure, that this question is all right?

Comment: Yeah. The edited question is right. If you solved the previous question then there's surely some error in your solution :P One year younger? In tenth, and you already know calculus? Which school do you go to man :P

Comment: KhanAcademy school! Best ever!

Comment: Lol. Let me guess. You're preparing for JEE. :P

Comment: How would equating make LHS = RHS?

Comment: Equating and then simplification. I couldn't do it, I was somewhat busy, sorry. And Mann's solution is better! (y)